# Android extra with intent is always NULL

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

For some reason I am having trouble retrieving my bundle extras from my intent. I am adding my extras to pass to my new activity with:

```
public void getMap(View view){

        Intent i = new Intent(this, BreweryYourTopBeers.class);
        Log.d("map" , e.beerBreweryId);
        i.putExtra("breweryID",  e.beerBreweryId);
        i.setClass(this, BreweryMap.class);

        startActivity(i);


    }
```

Looking at my LOG I can see that e.beerBreweryId does in fact have a value before it is bundled and sent.

But when I get to the next class I must not be retrieving the extras from my intent. I attempt to retrieve the value with:

```
public class BreweryMap extends ActionbarMenu {

    BeerData e;
    String beerID;
    GoogleMap map;

    //get beer details from bundle
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_brewerymap);

        //get brewery data

        //get beer data
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String breweryID = extras.getString("brewreyID");


        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();



        //todo: get brewery latt and long and add marker
        //construct url
        String url = "http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/brewery/"+ breweryID +"?key=myKey&format=json&withLocations=y";

        Log.d("map", url);
        //async task to get beer taste tag percents
        new myAsyncTask(this,map).execute(url);

}
```

When I look at my log here the breweryID is always NULL and I can not figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got typographical error there

Try changing this line from

```
String breweryID = extras.getString("brewreyID");
```

to

```
String breweryID = extras.getString("breweryID");
```

Comment: DO you mean change the top line to the bottom line? If so what did I mess up, I still dont see it....

Comment: your spelling is wrong you typed brewreyID instead of breweryID

Comment: damn, I am dyslexic I did not see that till you pointed it out. Thanks, sometimes I just need an extra set of eyes on my code.

Comment: Its ok bro. Maybe you can tick the check mark if if I answered it right?

Comment: Yea it said I had to wait three minutes. I wouldn't leave you hanging buddy.

Answer (score 3):

As @Rick Royd Aban said, you have a typo in your code with switched e & r in one string.

this is why you should never use strings directly but rather do something like this:

```
public static final String EXTRA_BREWERY_ID = "brewery_id";
i.putExtra(EXTRA_BREWERY_ID,  e.beerBreweryId);
String breweryID = extras.getString(EXTRA_BREWERY_ID);
```

This way : 
if you make a typo, your code won't compile, way better than to have to track the bug and it makes reusing it way easier and maintenable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();  
String breweryID = intent.getStringExtra("brewreyID");
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by this.  What was the OP's problem?  Why does this work?